# Java : search for multiple fields in an index in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

What I'm trying to achieve here is to search for two fields in an index.
The structure looks like this in kibana :

```
POST arempris/emptagnames
{
  "mappings" : {
    "emptags":{
          "properties": {
                "employeeid": {
                  "type":"integer"
                },
                "tagName": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fielddata": true,
                  "analyzer": "english"
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

In java, I had written a code to search for the single field named "tagName" and return the searchHits in jsonArrayBuilder format.

Similarly to this, in this case, is it possible to search employeeid first and then return the list of tagNames associated to that employeeid?

In case of RDBMS, my query would look like : 
SELECT tagNames from filemetadata where employeeid = 124 and tagName like %slip% and this is what I'm looking to implement using QueryBuilder. Is it possible to implement?

The java code to search for a single field in the index what I've written is :

```
Client esclient = getClient();

        String index = "arempris";
        String type = "tags";

        QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.matchPhrasePrefixQuery("tagName", tagName);
        SearchResponse response = esclient.prepareSearch(index).setTypes(type)
                .setQuery(query)
                .execute().actionGet();

        hits = response.getHits().getHits();
        System.out.println(hits.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(hits[i].getSourceAsString());
        }
```

Would greatly appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `bool query` with `must` clause to have the `AND` behaviour. You can use a `term` query for the exact match and a `wildcard` query for the `like`

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = new BoolQueryBuilder();
query.must(new WildcardQueryBuilder("tagName", "*slip*"));
query.must(new TermQueryBuilder("employeeid", 123));
```

Comment: ya, forgot to mention, it's showing result for only lowercase entries, for case insensitive, what do we need to add anything?

Comment: Yes you have to create a custom analyzer that will use the english analyzer and also lowercase. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/analysis-custom-analyzer.html

Comment: Sorry I had difficulty understanding it, I tried it, can you provide an example? or any other reference link?

Comment: Please open a new topic. There is no use for anyone else if we solve it here.

Comment: Having started elasticsearch yesterday, I'm a novice at this, that's the reason I was seeking assistance. Sorry if I had wasted your time. But thanks for your help.

Comment: You haven't. This is not about elastic or anything else, it's how stackoverflow works. You make a question, you get an answer. If you have another question then you open a new thread. Probably I'll try to answer it as well, but in order for this answer to be useful to anyone else, then it must have it own topic. Answers in comments are not the way to go.

Comment: Yes.Understood and no offence. Actually want to thank you for taking your time to respond to me.